# no such ctrl error message from OV5642 camera driver

Tags: samsung, camera, system-error

I am running a third party android application that scans QR code using a camera. When the application connects to the camera I get a device Error message on the minicom terminal

> OV5642 1-003c: ov5642_g_ctrl: no such ctrl 0x8000067

What does this message mean? what could be going wrong?

I am running my application on Samsung Exynos MV4412 test board, with Android v4.0.3, Kernel v3.0.15.

I see the camera display after the application connects to it, it shows a green overlay area where to place the QR code, but it doesn't seem to automatically recognize and scan the QR code.

Comment: Maybe the app is trying to access a system-unsupported feature? If so, please contact the developer of the app for further help.